# constructors basic (reference to distance is ambiguous)

Tags: c++, constructor

I was practicing constructors. Below is the code which I was practicing but got an error that
"reference to distance is ambiguous" I could not identify my error, Please help me. I have been trying that .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

//distance

class distance
{
public:
    distance(int met, int cen);
    distance(int met);
    void display();

private:
    int meters;
    int centimeters;

};


distance::distance(int met, int cen){
cout<<"Object have been initialized and assigned the values"<<endl;
meters=met;
centimeters=cen;

}
distance::distance(int met){
meters=met;
cout<<"One member has been initialized "<<endl;
cout<<"Please enter the distance in centimeters"<<endl;
cin>>centimeters;

}

void distance::display(){
cout<<"The distance in centimeters is "<<centimeters<<endl;
cout<<"The distance in meters is "<<meters<<endl;

}   
int main(){
//explicit call
distance a=distance(10,20);
a.display();
int c,m;
cout<<"Enter the distance in centimeters and meters"<<endl;
cin>>c>>m;

//implicit call
distance dist(c,m);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the error as it's displayed? (meaning copy and paste)

Comment: \main.cpp|45|error: reference to 'distance' is ambiguous|

Comment: @user3188072 update the question with the error please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

stop doing

```
using namespace std;
```

your `distance` is conflicting with `std::distance`.

A quick/dirty fix is replace all your `distance` in main with `::distance`, a more robust fix is to add `std::` to all standard library call and get rid of `using namespace std;`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that standard C++ namespace std:: uses already name distance for declaring a function. As you specified directive `using namespace std;` then you introduced this standard name in your declarative region i.e. in the global namespace.

To make the program to work in function main prefix all occurences of distance with two colons. For example

```
::distance a=::distance(10,20);
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This ambiguous errors occur due to using std functions as general functions. There are two ways to overcome this.

1) Instead of declaring using namespace std; use `std::cout` whenever you need to print any `std::cin` to take values and `std::endl` for new line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

//distance

class distance
{
public:
    distance(int met, int cen);
    distance(int met);
    void display();

private:
    int meters;
    int centimeters;

};


distance::distance(int met, int cen){
std::cout<<"Object have been initialized and assigned the values"<<std::endl;
meters=met;
centimeters=cen;

}
distance::distance(int met){
meters=met;
std::cout<<"One member has been initialized "<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Please enter the distance in centimeters"<<std::endl;
std::cin>>centimeters;

}

void distance::display(){
std::cout<<"The distance in centimeters is "<<centimeters<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"The distance in meters is "<<meters<<std::endl;

}   
int main(){
//explicit call
distance a=distance(10,20);
a.display();
int c,m;
std::cout<<"Enter the distance in centimeters and meters"<<std::endl;
std::cin>>c>>m;

//implicit call
distance dist(c,m);
return 0;
}
```

2)  You can also change the `distance` to `Distance` to not conflict with the inbuilt `std::distance` function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

//Distance

class Distance
{
public:
    Distance(int met, int cen);
    Distance(int met);
    void display();

private:
    int meters;
    int centimeters;

};


Distance::Distance(int met, int cen){
cout<<"Object have been initialized and assigned the values"<<endl;
meters=met;
centimeters=cen;

}
Distance::Distance(int met){
meters=met;
cout<<"One member has been initialized "<<endl;
cout<<"Please enter the Distance in centimeters"<<endl;
cin>>centimeters;

}

void Distance::display(){
cout<<"The Distance in centimeters is "<<centimeters<<endl;
cout<<"The Distance in meters is "<<meters<<endl;

}   
int main(){
//explicit call
Distance a=Distance(10,20);
a.display();
int c,m;
cout<<"Enter the Distance in centimeters and meters"<<endl;
cin>>c>>m;

//implicit call
Distance dist(c,m);
return 0;
}
```