# Why am I getting error "reference to struct_tag is ambiguous" with using namespace std?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I was trying to write a function with a return type of *struct variable.* If I use `using namespace std;` I get an error but if instead use `std::` the program runs fine.

**The erroneous code:**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct distance
{
    int feet;
    int inches;
};
distance foo(distance, distance);
int main()
{
    distance d1, d2;
    cout << "Input feet of d1: ";     cin >> d1.feet;
    cout << "\nInput inches of d1: "; cin >> d1.inches;
    cout << "\nInput feet of d2: ";   cin >> d2.feet;
    cout << "\nInput inches of d2: "; cin >> d2.inches;
    distance large = foo(d1, d2);
    cout << "The larger distance is: " << large.feet << "\'-" << large.inches << "\"";
}
distance foo(distance d1, distance d2)
{
    float temp1 = d1.feet + d1.inches/12;
    float temp2 = d2.feet + d2.inches/12;
    if(temp1>temp2) return d1;
    else return d2;
}
```

Error: Reference to `distance` is ambiguous.

**Working code without namespace std:**

```
#include<iostream>

struct distance
{
    int feet;
    int inches;
};
distance foo(distance, distance);
int main()
{
    distance d1, d2;
    std::cout << "Input feet of d1: "; std::cin >> d1.feet;
    std::cout << "\nInput inches of d1: "; std::cin >> d1.inches;
    std::cout << "\nInput feet of d2: "; std::cin >> d2.feet;
    std::cout << "\nInput inches of d2: "; std::cin >> d2.inches;
    distance large = foo(d1, d2);
    std::cout << "The larger distance is: " << large.feet << "\'-" << large.inches << "\"";
}
distance foo(distance d1, distance d2)
{
    float temp1 = d1.feet + d1.inches/12;
    float temp2 = d2.feet + d2.inches/12;
    if(temp1>temp2) return d1;
    else return d2;
}
```

As far as I know namespace std has objects like `cout, cin` etc. But what does it have to do with structures? Why does `using namespace std` give error while directly using `std::` runs the program smoothly?

Comment: `Error: Reference to distance is ambiguous.` What do you think that could possibly mean?

Comment: Because there's [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks. I didn't know that there is an distance structure in std namespace.

Comment: It's too bad there is no way to search this kind of thing on the web.

Comment: @juanchopanza I searched it many times but couldn't find nothing useful.

Comment: @user31782 There also many other common words in std namespace: function, plus, less, set, pair, copy, unique...

Comment: First hit I get: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21079186/constructors-basic-reference-to-distance-is-ambiguous

Comment: @juanchopanza I was searching with _reference to structure is ambiguous_, _reference to structure tag is ambiguous_ and _reference to structure variable is ambiguous_. I thought _distance_ is particular struct tag of my program so other question might have different tags. I accept that I didn't search in _Search engines_ well. I accept the downvotes. And thanks for mentioning the would-be reason of downvotes.

Comment: I think your first hit http://stackoverflow.com/q/21079186/3429430 is a better duplicate for my question. Or perhaps both these questions are duplicate of the more general question http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/3429430

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `using namespace std;` exactly because this (and even worse) might happen.

In your case the compiler doesn't know which `distance` you are referring to: It could be either your own or [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)

If you want to avoid writing `std::cout` every time you can just write `using std:: cout`.
That will tell your compiler where to look when you use `cout`.

Comment: Isn't writing `std::cout` shorter than `using std:: cout`?

Comment: No, you got me wrong. instead of `using namespace std;` you write `using std::cout; using std::endl;`. You can then use `cout` and `endl` directly without having to add the prefix `std::` every time.

Comment: Oh. Means we need not to invoke the whole namespce rather we can tell the compiler to add certain elements like `cout` or `cin` by writing using std::cout instead of `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Exactly. Like in @MikeCAT's answer

Answer (score 1):

As the message sugggests, the name `distance` is ambigious between [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) and the structure you defined.

You can write

```
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
// more using for identifiers from namespace std to use
```

instead of `using namespace std;`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that there is an distance structure in std namespace.